# Key Codes for diacritics

Tags: android, keyboard, diacritics

Where can I found out key codes for diacritics? Letters ā, č, ē, ģ, ī, ķ, ļ, ņ, š, ū, ž?
I want to make a custom keyboard for latvian language with all Latvian alphabet.

Comment: keycodes are keyboard mapping specific. that's probably not what you want. you probably want unicode values

Answer (score 1):

You could consult a Unicode chart like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). Also [this](http://www.geocities.ws/click2speak/unicode/chars_lv.html) is a smaller chart so you don't have to ferret through the larger Unicode list. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it with 2 ways. The first is to pick the unicode, the second is combine regular with diacristics.
check unicode mapping
[in WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this website. 
There is Quick Lookup on TopRight of webpage.
If you put any characters what you want to know, it will tell you.

http://www.unicodemap.org/